# Merge apple and osx tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I don't have enough score to suggest a synonymous, but I think that the [apple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) tags on parent should be either synonymous, or simply merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. Since there are 24 [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) questions and all 3 [apple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) questions deal with OS X, I merged [apple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) into [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx). I keep [apple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) as synonym for [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx). It's not set in stone: we might change that if another OS version of Apple appears, or if iOS gets TeX support.